# Why is layout_marginBottom ignored when using wrap_content?

Tags: android, margin, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/usericon_img"
    android:layout_width="73.3334dp"
    android:layout_height="70.6667dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2.6667dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3.3334dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.6667dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

On the emulator (I've tested it on a real device and it looks the same) the layout looks like this:

[image]

My question is: why I don't have a red margin under the white layout? I know that if I change the outer layout to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="76dp"
android:background="#FF0000" >
```

I'll get what I want, but why doesn't `wrap_content` work properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins):

> To measure its dimensions, a view takes into account its padding.

If I am not mistaken it means that margin is not added to the dimension. That means wrap_content works correctly but don't take margin into account.

Just a short question: Why do you use values like `70.6667dp`?

Comment: I've used 70.6667 because I want a dimension of 106 pixels on a hdpi screen.

Comment: if margins are ignored, why do I have left and top margins?

Comment: The margins are ignored while the size is measured but you still see them (at least top and left are visible while bottom will be outside the visible red area).

Comment: @Toorop, I'm a little late here but you realise that the DPI of HDPI is only approximate yes?